# Is it possible to display percentage and count together?

Tags: tableau-api, stacked-chart

I have created a 100.00% stacked bar chart in Tableau, and I want to know if I can show the total count of entries within each category next to the percentage that is listed.

This is what I currently have:

[image]

And this is what I want:

```
_____________________________________________
|______66.66% (666)______|___33.33% (333)___|
```

Is this possbile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, drag your measure to the text shelf and set it a percent of total like you have done in columns. Place the same measure again in the text shelf. Click the Label button and you can edit the label as follows

```
<% of Total SUM(Quantity)> (<SUM(Quantity)>)
```

See sample workbook here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gn8hfazwvp80ad1/170726%20stack%20question.twbx?dl=0

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me as I do not have a `Quantity` dimension to select.  Do you know of an alternative approach?

Comment: I should also mention that I have the `Percentage of` option set to `Row` under the `Analysis` menu, something which I noticed your sample workbook doesn't have.  Once I set yours to this option, the labels stopped working as they should. Each time I add `<% of Total...>` to the calculated field in my workbook, it isn't recognised (unless I change the setting back to `Percentage of` option back to `Row`.

Comment: "Quantity" is irrelevant. Number of Records works just fine. That was just an example. I've updated my linked workbook to show Number of Records. If you can share a sample workbook, that would be great.

Comment: I have it working, but the problem for me now is that I am unable to sort my bars as 100.00% stacks (asked in a previous question) because this disrupts the label formats (treats everything as percentages or values between 0 and 1). Is there a workaround? Also, I'm afraid I cannot post a sample workbook as the data are confidential.

Answer (score 0):

I think solution that will work in your situation is to copy *Number of Records* and call it *Number of Records Percentage*. Then change number format to Percentage (right click / number format / percentage). 
Then you will have two fields - *Number of Records* generated automatically, and yours copy *Number of Records Percentage*. Then put both to Labels.
For both fields you can set different table calculations.